# AOSP (Android 7). Add prebuilt library to the system

Tags: android-source, android-7.0-nougat, ninja, android-7.1-nougat

I have prebuilt jar library and I want to add it to AOSP android 7.
But, as I know, in order to use library I should have .jack library to.

Am I wrong or no?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit? Which prebuilt jar library?

Comment: Hockeyapp jar library